# On the duality gap for quasiconvex optimisation problems

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146480/why-is-convexity-more-important-than-quasi-convexity-in-optimization) stack exchange question got me thinking about quasiconvex analysis.

Given a compact,convex subset $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a quasiconvex function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Define the double Legendre-Fenchel transform of $f$, written $f^{**}$, given by: $$\operatorname{epi} (f^{**})=\operatorname{co}(\operatorname{epi}(f))$$ where $\operatorname{epi}(f)\in X\times\mathbb{R}$ is the epigraph of f, and $\operatorname{co}$ is the convex hull of a set.

Assume $f$ has a unique minimum

I know that bad things can happen here if $X$ is not compact, but for the closed and bounded case, it seems like $f^{**}$ can also only have a single minimum on $X$, and this will also minimize $f$. Does someone have a counter-example or a proof?

My intuition has failed me often enough in the past, so I thought I would ask before making an ass of myself.

**EDIT:** I decided to provide a (simple) example which is indicative of my intuition on this matter. Consider $f(x)=\sqrt{\left| x\right| }$. If we take the domain to be the entire real axis, then $f^{**}\equiv 0$. But for any closed interval $[a,b]$ , $(f\left| _{[a,b]} \right.)^{**}$ fulfills the qualities that I ask for in my question.

Comment: I think you need take closure to $f^{**}$ be well-defined  i.e $\operatorname{epi} (f^{**})=  \operatorname{cl} \operatorname{co}(\operatorname{epi}(f))$

Comment: I proved your claim, it is true for any lsc function defined on compact interval, and quasiconvexity  does not play any role!

Comment: but I'm lazy to type here..

Comment: @Ashkan I was specifically interested in the quasiconvex case. Unless you also proved that lsc is a necessary condition, your result doesn't really interest me. It was a long time ago that I asked this question, but I think your result was known to me at the time.

Comment: once you define $f^{**}$ is this form $\operatorname{epi} (f^{**})=\operatorname{co}(\operatorname{epi}(f))$ you need assume $f$ is lsc, other wise  $\operatorname{co}(\operatorname{epi}(f))$  it is not closed set... and so there is no function like $f^{**}$ such that $\operatorname{epi} (f^{**})=\operatorname{co}(\operatorname{epi}(f))$...   so lsc is zero condition here.    BTW I am interested to see your proof for lsc, or any reference about it if you have seen somewhere , since mine is rather complicated ... want to see simple proof, thanks

Comment: @Ashkan First off, forgive me if I make mistakes, since I haven't thought about this topic in a long time. I see the point you are making now. Taking the floor function as a counterexample, we can choose the domain such that the convex hull of the epigraph is not the epigraph of any function. So my definition is not well-formed.

Comment: If the function $f$ is lsc, then my definition is fine. If I want to include functions which aren't lsc, then I need to add the closure to my definition like you suggested. That implies $f^{**}$ is lsc by construction. But unless I am missing something again, that doesn't further restrict $f$ to be lsc.